# How change the branding text with an icon and put it in front of ribbon row?

Tags: css, branding

I am trying to change the branding text with an icon, which comes over the ribbonrow. I made this css file:

```
#s4-ribbonrow {z-index:-1; position: static;}
```

The icon looks good but the ribbon-row does not work anymore, I mean the Browse/files/library tabs. How can I make it, so the icon stays on top and the tabs work as well?
If I use the Z-index, the ribonnrow will be deactivated.

Comment: please add a screenshot to show in where you want to change branding text. do you mean changing "Sharepoint" top most row text?

Comment: @imanabidi yes, I have changed the Sharepoint text to an icon. but its bigger the suitebar area, I put the ribbonrow at the back with Z-index and the Logo is now at the top. the problem is that by making Ribbonrow as Z-index:-1 then the tabs for Library and Files does not work anymore, it wil be disabled.